# kendoGrid popup custom validation, multiple fields

Tags: angular, validation, kendo-ui

I have an ASP.NET Core, Angular (2) grid and popup and I am trying to implement custom validation on more than one field.

If I try to implement two versions of custom validation, shown below, then the second validation doesn't run until the first *passes*, which is fine, but then the second validation message does not appear in the popup.

```
schema: {
      model: {
        id: "contactID",
        fields: {
          contactID: { type: "number" },
          lastName: { type: "string" },
          firstName: { type: "string" },
          name: { type: "string" },
          jobTitle: { type: "string" },
          jobTitleID: {
            type: "number",
            validation: {
              jobTitleIdValidation: function (input, params) {

                if (input.is("[name='jobTitleID']")) {
                  var $jobTitleId = kendo.jQuery('#jobTitleID');
                  var jobTitleIdValue = $jobTitleId.data("kendoComboBox").value();

                  if (parseInt(jobTitleIdValue, 10) === 0 || !jobTitleIdValue) {
                    $jobTitleId.attr('data-jobTitleIdValidation-msg', 'Job title is required');
                    return false;
                  } else {
                    return true;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          office: {
            type: "string"
          },
          officeID: {
            type: "number",
            validation: {
              officeIdValidation: function (input, params) {

                if (input.is("[name='officeID']")) {
                  var $officeId = kendo.jQuery('#officeID');
                  var officeIdValue = $officeId.data("kendoComboBox").value();

                  if (parseInt(officeIdValue, 10) === 0 || !officeIdValue) {
                    $officeId.attr('data-officeIdValidation-msg', 'Office is required');
                    return false;
                  } else {
                    return true;
                  }
                } else {
                  return true;  // for any other input
                }
              }
            }
          },
```

Template code fragment:

```
      editable: {
        mode: "popup",
        template:
`<div id="details" _ngcontent-c2>
<div><label for="firstName">First Name</label>
<input id="firstName" data-bind="value: firstName" /></div>
<div><label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
<input id="lastName" data-bind="value: lastName" /></div>
<div><label for="email">Email</label>
<input id="email" data-bind="value: email" /></div>
<div><label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input id="phone" data-bind="value: phone" /></div>
<div><label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
<input id="mobile" data-bind="value: mobile" /></div>
<div><label for="jobTitleID">Job Title</label>
<input id="jobTitleID" name="jobTitleID" data-bind="value: jobTitleID" /></div>
<div class="validator-msg"><span data-for="jobTitleID" class="k-invalid-msg"></span></div>
<div><label for="officeID">Office</label>
<input id="officeID" name="officeID" data-bind="value: officeID" /></div>
<div class="validator-msg"><span data-for="officeID" class="k-invalid-msg"></span></div>
</div>
```

If, however, I attempt all the validation in one custom validation rule (which seems to be expected), and using one validation message-span (under jobTitleId) it does not display a message for officeID after the jobTitleID has been provided. Code here:

```
          jobTitleID: {
            type: "number",
            validation: {
              customValidation: function (input, params) {

                var $jobTitleId = kendo.jQuery('#jobTitleID');

                if (input.is("[name='jobTitleID']")) {
                  var jobTitleIdValue = $jobTitleId.data("kendoComboBox").value();

                  if (parseInt(jobTitleIdValue, 10) === 0 || !jobTitleIdValue) {
                    $jobTitleId.attr('data-customValidation-msg', 'Job title is required');
                    return false;
                  } else {
                    return true;
                  }
                } else if (input.is("[name='officeID']")) {
                  var officeIdValue = kendo.jQuery('#officeID').data("kendoComboBox").value();

                  if (parseInt(officeIdValue, 10) === 0 || !officeIdValue) {
                    $jobTitleId.attr('data-customValidation-msg', 'Office is required');
                    return false;
                  } else {
                    return true;
                  }
                } else {
                  return true;  // for any other input
                }
              }
            }
```

How can I get this to behave correctly? I suspect it has something to do with `return true` at the end(?)

Note that I don't want to just use the `required: true attribute` because a default 0 value is being displayed and I will also need to validate a combination of fields.

Comment: My attempt at this custom validation also mucks up the data binding of inputs. On attempting to save, I have to use the save event to set `e.model.property` to the val() (or value()) read from the input/component.

Comment: really is Angular??

Comment: The overall application is .NET Core MVC and Angular. The pages and components are assembled with Angular for an SPA but, within each component, I have Kendo controls. These are essentially Kendo UI for jQuery components, with their data sourced via Angular services.

Comment: I suppose I could have also used Kendo UI for Angular (rather than for jQuery) but we already had a lot of code that I could borrow for jQuery and I felt that the documentation for the Angular (2) version was thin on the ground.

Comment: i guess this line of code may be causing the issue `else if (input.is("[name='officeID']")) {`. Try removing the `else` from here.
And yes ofcourse, you would need to remove the return statements from everywhere and place a single return statement at the end of the function. This would execute all the statements prior to returning anything from the function.